# Improving run time of SQL - currently 61 hours

Tags: sql, optimization, teradata

Complex select statement with approximately 20 left outer join statements. Many of the joins are essential to obtain data from a single column in that table (poorly designed database). The current runtime using EXPLAIN is estimated at 61 hours (45GB).

I have limited options due to user permissions. How can I optimise the SQL?

identifying and removing unnecessary joins
writing statements to include data rather than exclude data I don't need
trying to get user permission to CREATE Table ('hell no')
trying to get access to a sandpit like space on a server to create a view ('oh hells no no no').

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column1, t3.column2, t4.column3
--- (etc - approximately 30 items)

, CASE WHEN t1.column2 is NULL
THEN t2.column3 
ELSE t1.column2
END as Derived_Column_1

FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column3

LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 T3
ON T1.column5 = t3.column6
AND t1.column6 = t3.column7

LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE4 T4
ON T2.Column4 = T4.Column8
AND T2.Column5 = '16'

--- (etc - approximately 16 other joins, some of which are only required to connect table 1 to 5, because they have no direct common fields)

--- select data that was timestamped in the last 120 days
WHERE CAST(t1.Column3 as Date) > CURRENT_DATE - 120

-- de-duplify the data by four values and use the latest entry
QUALIFY RANK() (PARTITION BY t1.column1, t2.column1, t3.column2, t3.column4 ORDER BY t1.Column3 desc) = 1
```

Single output that has 30 fields + derived_column field
for data that was timestamped in the last 120 days.

Would like to remove duplicates based on four fields but the QUALIFY RANK() (PARTITION BY t1.column1, t2.column1, t3.column2, t3.column4 ORDER BY t1.Column3 desc) = 1 adds a lot of time to the run.

Comment: What a mess. What's the format of `t1.Column3`?

Comment: And you mention fairly limited priviledges, are you able to create indexes?

Comment: I have select statement permissions and that's it. I will need to check whether I can create an index on Monday. The query will be loaded to Tableau as a custom SQL script which I *think* doesn't allow volatile tables.

and yes, its a freaking mess! t1.Column3 original datatype is timestamp. I haven't specified a format but it defaults to 2019-08-09.

Comment: Have you checked if those joins are actually 1-many? If they're many-many you will increase the number of rows with each join.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you could `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE ... ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` to store some intermediate data.** It may need some checking, but I think you would not need any special rights to do that (only a spool space quota you already have as a means to run your `SELECT`'s).

**The usual optimization technique is as follows:** you take control of the execution plan by cutting your large `SELECT` to pieces, which sequentially compute intermediate results (saving those into volatile tabless) and redistribute them (by specifying the `PRIMARY KEY` on the volatile tables) to take advantage of the Teradata parallelism.

Usually, you choose the columns that are used in join conditions as a primary index; you may encounter a skew, which you may solve by cutting your intermediate volatile table in two and choosing different primary indexes for the two parts. That would make your code more sophisticated, but much more optimal.

By the way, **do not let the "hours" estimate of the Teradata plan fool you**; those are not the actual hours, minutes or seconds, only synthetic ones. Usually, they are pretty far from the actual query run time.